# For which $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^a}{x^2+y^2}$ with $f(0,0)=0$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

My function is defined as:
$$f(x,y) =  \begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{xy^a}{x^2+y^2}&(x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
     \ 0&(x,y) = (0,0)
   \end{cases}
$$

I want to find out for which $a\in \mathbb{R}$ the function is continuous. I am not quite sure how to solve something like this. I know that for $a=1$ the function is definitely not continuous, which can be checked, since $(\frac1n,\frac1n)$ converges to $(0,0)$ but $f(\frac1n,\frac1n)$ does not. Now if I want $f$ to be steady in $(0,0)$, I figured that this is the case if $a>1$. But this is where I get stuck. How to I prove or check, if for $a>1$ the rest of the function is continuous as well? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: @Jack I have not, but I would not know how to, I just started learning about continuity of functions, so the tools that I have to solve such problems are very limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exercise** 1.

> Note that *if* $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$
>   $$
> \left|\frac{xy^a}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac{r^{1+a}}{r^2}\vert\cos\theta\sin^a\theta\vert\leq r^{a-1}.
> $$
>   which gives you a *sufficient* condition that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$: $a>1$.

On the other hand, you want also a *necessary* condition.

**Exercise** 2.

> Show that when $a\leq 1$, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Again, consider $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ and
$$
\frac{xy^a}{x^2+y^2}=r^{a-1}\cos\theta\sin^a\theta.
$$
If $a<1$, then $f$ is not even bounded near $(0,0)$, which tells (why?) you that $f$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$. If $a=1$, then 
$$
\frac{xy^a}{x^2+y^2}=\cos\theta\sin^a\theta
$$
which depends on $\theta$, this implies (why?) that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{r\to0}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\lim_{r\to 0}r^{a-1}\cos\theta\sin^a\theta$$
Note that the limit equals $0$ if it exists, and if limit equals $0$ implies $f$ is continuous.
The limit does not exist implies that $f$ is not continuous at the origin. And for $a\le 1$, the limit does not exist

So $f$ is continuosu for $a>1$

Comment: This is a really useful trick! This would solve it for any $a$ and not just integer values.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tricks to these types of limit problems. Solving them seems a bit ad hoc/heuristic at times. You are correct, for $a=1$ this is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. In general you want to check that the exponents in the numerator and denominator don't add to the same integer value for $a$. Note that for $a=1$ $lim_{x,y\rightarrow (0,0)}$ $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ does not exist along the path $y=x$ because we get that the limit is equal to $1/2$. If we have $a\geq2$ this cannot happen, and the function will be continuous at the origin if we take the limit along any path heading towards $(0,0)$. You can save yourself algebra this way as well rather than finding convergent sequences like ${1/n}$ for the coordinates $(x,y)$. Also, you can try to use polar coordinates as the answers above indicated by simply substituting $x=rcos(\theta)$ and $y=rsin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

The point where you may have some problems is the origin right?

So let's see what happens when we take the limit in polar coordinates:
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r\cos t r^a\sin^a t}{r^2}=
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r^{a+1}\cos t \sin^a t}{r^2}
$$ 
Which you need to tend to 0 independently of $t$. From this, it can be seen that you must have $a+1>2\Rightarrow a>1$